# How do I use intersection() across three columns only where columns values are not empty?

Tags: python, pandas

I have three object type columns which are storing title numbers in lists. I'd like to find the intersection like so

```
results_df['TITLE_MATCH'] = ""

results_df['TITLE_MATCH'] = [set(a).intersection(b).intersection(c) for a,b,c in zip(results_df['RTITLE_TITLENO'], results_df['RWRITER_TITLENO'], results_df['RARTIST_TITLENO'])]
```

but sometimes the value in any column is blank, resulting in no intersection. I tried using if-else logic and truth values but I don't know how to do it correctly and run into errors. How can I rewrite the truth values to run the intersection I want? The following is my code

```
results_df['TITLE_MATCH'] = ""

for index, row in results_df.iterrows():
    if results_df['RTITLE_TITLENO'] and results_df['RWRITER_TITLENO'] and results_df['RARTIST_TITLENO']:
        results_df['TITLE_MATCH'] = [set(a).intersection(b).intersection(c) for a,b,c in zip(results_df['RTITLE_TITLENO'], results_df['RWRITER_TITLENO'], results_df['RARTIST_TITLENO'])]
    elif results_df['RTITLE_TITLENO'] and results_df['RWRITER_TITLENO'] and not results_df['RARTIST_TITLENO']:
        results_df['TITLE_MATCH'] = [set(a).intersection(b) for a,b in zip(results_df['RTITLE_TITLENO'], results_df['RWRITER_TITLENO'])]
    elif results_df['RTITLE_TITLENO'] and not results_df['RWRITER_TITLENO'] and results_df['RARTIST_TITLENO']:
        results_df['TITLE_MATCH'] = [set(a).intersection(c) for a,c in zip(results_df['RTITLE_TITLENO'], results_df['RARTIST_TITLENO'])]
    else:
        results_df['TITLE_MATCH'] = "ERROR"
```

Here is a sample of my data set.

```
      RTITLE     RWRITER RARTIST     RTITLE_FUZZY                                       RTITLE_TITLENO                                    RWRITER_FUZZY  RWRITER_TITLENO RARTIST_FUZZY  RARTIST_TITLENO

38652 SUMMERTIME NaN     NEWELL OLER (SUMMERTIME, SUMMERTIME, SUMMERTIME, SUMMERTIM...  [2790402, 2790402, 1428694, 9117704, 722134, 1... NaN            NaN             (NEWELL OLER,) [2790402]
```

I used fuzzywuzzy to look up title, writer and artist (first three columns) to viable title numbers and stored them in a list. Now I would like to find the set or intersection of the title number lists found from the three separate fuzzywuzzy searches, excluding where either RWRITER_TITLENO or RARTIST_TITLENO is blank, for every row. Because the artist or writer field can sometimes be empty, I do not want to penalize the set or intersection results.

Comment: How is a `blank` represented in your dataframe? `None`? `np.nan`?

Comment: They are np.nan

Comment: Please show an example of your dataset - there may be another way to accomplish the result.